# String a float en php

Tags: php

Hola estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de pasar un sting a float en php, la cosa es que lo he intentado de todas las formas posibles pero siempre pierdo los decimales.
Os pongo un ejemplo del codigo:

```
$for($i=0; $i sizeof($arrayPrecios; $++){    
     $iva21 = $iva21 + (float)$arrayPrecios[$i][precioSinIva];    
}
```

Siempre me devuelve 6 como respuesta.

Comment: no entiendo este ejemplo, porque no pones el código completo? aquí no estás pasando ningún string a float.. ya que precionormal le estas enviando un float directamente

Comment: Los precios vienen en un array, pero al intentar cambiarlos a float siempre pierdo los decimales, tambien he intentado con number_format, pero nada, me devuelve 6.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHP**

```
$string = '15.6555';
$float = (float) $string;

echo $float;
```

Esto funciona correctamente. La impresión que me da es que el separador de decimales del `string` que estás tratando de convertir a `float`, en tu caso se trata de una "coma" en vez de un "punto". En ese caso deberías hacer algo como esto:

**PHP**

```
$string = '15,6555';
$string = str_replace ( ',', '.', $string);
$float = (float) $string;

echo $float;
```

Recuerda que el separador de decimales en cualquier lenguaje de programación es el "punto".

Comment: Funciona! Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con floatval($valorstr)
http://php.net/manual/es/function.floatval.php

Comment: Lo he probado y me sigue borrando los decimales